# Shell Script compare file content with a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, file-comparison

I have a String "ABCD" and a file test.txt. I want to check if the file has only this content "ABCD".
Usually I get the file with "ABCD" only and I want to send email notifications when I get anything else apart from this string so I want to check for this condition.
Please help!

Comment: Are you using a bash script? You can grab the contents of test.txt by doing  `cat test.txt` and then compare with your string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Update: My original answer would unnecessarily read a large file into memory when it couldn't possibly match. Any multi-line file would fail, so you only  need to read two lines at most. Instead, read the first line. If it does not match the string, *or* if a second `read` succeeds at all, regardless of what it reads, then send the e-mail.

```
str=ABCD
if { IFS= read -r line1 &&
     [[ $line1 != $str ]] ||
     IFS= read -r $line2
   } < test.txt; then
    # send e-mail
fi
```

---

Just read in the entire file and compare it to the string:

```
str=ABCD
if [[ $(< test.txt) != "$str" ]]; then
    # send e-mail
fi
```

Comment: Second option also allows to assert multiline text file content

Comment: I had to do `if [[ "$(< test.txt)" != "$str" ]]; then` to get the second option to work properly for multiline files. Note the quotes.

Answer (score 15):

Something like this should work:

```
s="ABCD"
if [ "$s" == "$(cat test.txt)" ] ;then
    :
else
    echo "They don't match"
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

```
str="ABCD"
content=$(cat test.txt)
if [ "$str" == "$content" ];then
    # send your email
fi
```

Comment: I think you may need to add a not to your if statement? The author sounds as if they want to send the email if the contents does not match

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ "$(cat test.tx)" == ABCD ]; then
           # send your email
else
    echo "Not matched"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using grep:

```
    if grep -qe ^$MY_STR$ myfile; then \
        echo "success"; \
    fi
```

Comment: This matches for all files where `MY_STR` is a sub-string, right? Poster want to match only files where `MY_STR` is the entire content. `^` and `$` is anchors for a line, the the entire file.