# How to compare a text file with a string in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to see if there is a string that exists in a particular text file that I have. I already referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259528/shell-script-compare-file-content-with-a-string) but I'm having different issues.

I'm running this as a batch file in powershell with `./test.bat`.

```
if [ "$(< C:/Temp/test.txt)" =~ "test" ]; then echo "true"
```

This returns `"$(C:/Temp/test.txt)" was unexpected at this time.`

I also tried

```
if grep -` "test" "$C:/Temp/test.txt"; then echo "True"
```

This returns `-q was unexpected at this time`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using the syntax of POSIX-compatible shells, such as Bash. Batch files have very different syntax.

Comment: `findstr test c:\temp\test.txt >NUL && echo True` is roughly the batch-file equivalent.

Comment: Or, less roughly, for the case insensitive substring: ```@"%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" /I "test" 0<"C:\Temp\test.txt" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo True) || Echo False```, or for the case insensitive word: ```@"%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /M /R "\<test\>" "C:\Temp\test.txt" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo True) || Echo False```.

Comment: @mklement0 is there an "else" equivalent? What if I want to throw an error or stop the batch file if the condition is not true?

Comment: @Sarah, you can then use the or conditional statement which is `||` as per example.`findstr test "c:\temp\test.txt" >NUL && echo True || echo False` or in the example where you also then want to exit. `findstr test "c:\temp\test.txt" >NUL && echo True || (echo False & exit /b 1)`

Answer (score -1):

To check if there's a string there in a specific file or not you can use grep command.

`grep -i -o "<your_string>" <your_file_name>`